# How to improve the speed of this code with double loops in Matlab? Is it possible?

Tags: matlab, performance, vectorization

Dear community of stack overflow. Is it possible to improve the speed of this code in Matlab? Can I use vectorization? Note that I have to use in every loop the "vpasolve" or "fsolve" function.

Here is the code which calls the function with a double loop:

```
   for i=1:1000
        for j=1:1000
            SilA(i,j)=SolW(i,j);  
        end
    end
```

Here is the function which is called by the above code. Can I vectorize the input of w, xi and make the code run faster?

```
function [ffw] = SolW(w,xi)

format long e;
z=0;mm=0.46;sop=80;
epit=0.1;voP=80.;
rho=2.1;aposC=0.1;aposD=0.1;
parEh=0.2*10^6;parEv=0.2*10^6;parGv=0.074*10^6;
parpos=0.35;hp=0.2;Ep=30*10^6;
parposV=0.20;ll=0.15;dd=2*ll;

 C11=(parEh*(parEv-parEh*parpos^2)/((1+parpos)*(parEv-parEv*parpos-2*parEh*parpos^2)))*(1+2*1i*aposD);
C13=(parEh*parEv*parpos/((parEv-parEv*parpos-2*parEh*parpos^2)))*(1+2*1i*aposD);
C33=((1-parpos)*parEv^2/(parEv-parEv*parpos-2*parEh*parpos^2))*(1+2*1i*aposD);
C44=parGv*(1+2*1i*aposD);
DD=(Ep*hp^3)/(12*(1-parposV^2));
a1=C44;
a2=C33;
c1=(C13+C44)*1i*xi;
c2=(C13+C44)*1i*xi;
b1=rho*w^2-C11*xi^2;
b2=rho*w^2-C44*xi^2;

 syms xr
rsol=vpasolve((a1*xr+b1).*(a2*xr+b2)-c1*c2*xr==0,xr);
rsol=eval(rsol);
r=[-sqrt(rsol)];
r1=r(1,:);
r2=r(2,:);


 Fdf1=sop*sqrt(2*pi/(1i*epit*xi))*exp(1i*(xi*voP+w)^2/(2*epit*xi));
BC11=C44*(r1-1i*xi*c2*r1/(a2*r1^2+b2));
BC21=(C13*1i*xi)-((C33*c2*r1^2)/(a2*r1^2+b2))+(DD*xi^4-mm*w^2+1i*aposC*w)*c2*r1/(a2*r1^2+b2);
BC12=C44*(r2-1i*xi*c2*r2/(a2*r2^2+b2));
BC22=(C13*1i*xi)-((C33*c2*r2^2)/(a2*r2^2+b2))+(DD*xi^4-mm*w^2+1i*aposC*w)*c2*r2/(a2*r2^2+b2);

 syms As1 As2;
   try
[Ass1,Ass2]=vpasolve(BC11*As1+BC12*As2==0,BC21*As1+BC22*As2+Fdf1==0,As1,As2);
       A1=eval(Ass1);
       A2=eval(Ass2);
   catch
       A1=0.0;
       A2=0.0;
   end


Bn1=-(c2*r1/(a2*r1^2+b2))*A1;
Bn2=-(c2*r2/(a2*r2^2+b2))*A2;
ffw=Bn1*exp(r1*z)+Bn2*exp(r2*z);

end
```

Comment: There is a way to vectorize your function call using `SilA = arrayfun(@SolW,x,y);`

Comment: Using `arrayfun` is not the same as vectorisation - it simply hides the loop (unless you're using `gpuArray` data, in which case `arrayfun` is (ironically) typically much more efficient than vectorisation)

Comment: Thank you! arrayfun seems to give me double speed than for loop.

Comment: However, I can not use arrayfun in nested loops.

Comment: 2 things are dodgy with those comments, **1.** it would be highly unusual to see that level of speed-up using `arrayfun`, since it's basically a loop. How are you timing / profiling this code? **2.** "I cannot use arrayfun in nested loops" doesn't mean a lot, since you can use it exactly how you would use loops, it just depends what you want to do! **End:** This is a poorly asked question because you provide no *context* for what you're trying to do, for someone to vectorize this, they'd have to blindly and slowly debug, understand, and improve on what you've done.

Comment: If you want to vectorize the function call you can use


`tic;
interval = 1:10;
x=repmat(interval,1,length(interval))';
y=repmat(interval,length(interval),1);y=y(:);
SilA = arrayfun(@SolW,x,y);
toc;`

which is not faster than the double loop. It is just more readable.

Comment: Are you pre-allocating your output array? That could be a major win right there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above program everything can be vectorized as @beesleep said above.
For example:

```
[I, J] = meshgrid(1:1000, 1:1000)
c1=(C13+C44)*1i.*xi;
c2=(C13+C44)*1i.*xi;
b1=rho.*w.^2 - C11.*xi.^2;
b2=rho.*w.^2-C44.*xi.^2;
```

The vpasolve part ,i.e.,

```
 syms xr
 rsol=vpasolve((a1*xr+b1).*(a2*xr+b2)-c1*c2*xr==0,xr);
 rsol=eval(rsol);
 r=[-sqrt(rsol)];
 r1=r(1,:);
 r2=r(2,:);
```

can also be vectorized by using fsolve as it is shown here:

```
fun=@(Xr) (a1.*Xr+b1).*(a2.*Xr+b2)-c1.*c2.*Xr
x01=-ones(2*Nxi);
x02=ones(2*Nxi);
options.Algorithm= 'trust-region-reflective'
options.JacobPattern=speye(4*Nxi^2);
options.PrecondBandWidth=0;
[rsol1]=fsolve(fun,x01,options);
[rsol2]=fsolve(fun,x02,options);
```

The other part, i.e,

```
 syms As1 As2;
 try
 [Ass1,Ass2]=vpasolve(BC11*As1+BC12*As2==0,BC21*As1+BC22*As2+Fdf1==0,As1,As2);
      A1=eval(Ass1);
      A2=eval(Ass2);
  catch
      A1=0.0;
      A2=0.0;
  end
```

since contains linear equations and in each row has two dependent equations can be solved as it is shown here:

```
 funAB1=@(As1) BC11.*As1+BC12.*((-Fdf2-BC21.*As1)./BC22);

 x0AB=ones(2*Nxi)+1i*ones(2*Nxi);
 options.Algorithm= 'trust-region-reflective';
 options.JacobPattern=speye(4*Nxi^2);
 options.PrecondBandWidth=0;
 [A1]=fsolve(funAB1,x0AB,options);

 A2=((-Fdf2-BC21.*A1)./BC22);
```

However, both can also be solved analytically, i.e.,

```
AAr=a1.*a2;
BBr=a1.*b2+b1.*a2-c1.*c2;
CCr=b1.*b2;

Xr1=(-BBr+sqrt(BBr^.2-4.*AAr.*CCr))./(2.*AAr);
Xr2=(-BBr-sqrt(BBr^.2-4.*AAr.*CCr))./(2.*AAr);
r1=-sqrt(Xr1(:,:));
r2=-sqrt(Xr2(:,:));
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything in your function but the calls to  `vpasolve`, and `try....` can be vectorize.

First, all this does not depend on `w` or `xi`, so **could be computed once only**:

```
format long e;
z=0;mm=0.46;sop=80;
epit=0.1;voP=80.;
rho=2.1;aposC=0.1;aposD=0.1;
parEh=0.2*10^6;parEv=0.2*10^6;parGv=0.074*10^6;
parpos=0.35;hp=0.2;Ep=30*10^6;
parposV=0.20;ll=0.15;dd=2*ll;

C11=(parEh*(parEv-parEh*parpos^2)/((1+parpos)*(parEv-parEv*parpos-2*parEh*parpos^2)))*(1+2*1i*aposD);
C13=(parEh*parEv*parpos/((parEv-parEv*parpos-2*parEh*parpos^2)))*(1+2*1i*aposD);
C33=((1-parpos)*parEv^2/(parEv-parEv*parpos-2*parEh*parpos^2))*(1+2*1i*aposD);
C44=parGv*(1+2*1i*aposD);
DD=(Ep*hp^3)/(12*(1-parposV^2));
a1=C44;
a2=C33;
```

From what I know, `eval` is slow, and I'm pretty sure that you don't need it:

```
rsol=eval(rsol);
```

Here is an example of vectorization. You should first generate all indices combination using meshgrid, and then use the `.` to noticed matlab to use element wise operations:

```
[I, J] = meshgrid(1:1000, 1:1000)
c1=(C13+C44)*1i.*xi;
c2=(C13+C44)*1i.*xi;
b1=rho.*w.^2 - C11.*xi.^2;
b2=rho.*w.^2-C44.*xi.^2;
```

But **you won't be able to vectorize** `vpasolve`, and `try....` litteraly, without changing it to something else. `vpasolve` is probably the bottleneck of you computation (**verify this using [matlab profiler](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html)**), so optimizing as proposed above will probably not reduce your computation time much.

Then you have several solutions:

- use `parfor` if you have access to it to parallelize your computations, which depending on your architecture, could give you a 4x speedup or so.
- it may be possible to linearize your equations and solve them all in one operation. Anyway, using a linear solver will be probably much faster than using `vpasolve`. **This will probably give you the fastest speedup (guessing factor 10 -100 ?)**
- because you have continuous data, you could reduce the number of steps, if you dare loosing precision.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable help! I appreciate it. Indeed, I changed the inner "for" with "parfor" and this gave me almos 4x more computation speed. Regarding the "arrayfun" I used only to compare with one loop and I saw that the speed was almost double, but maybe I did not measure correctly the time, I am not sure.  However, "parfor" as inner loop boosted my computation alot.

Comment: From what I know, except if you are using the GPU version, arrayfun should not speedup anything.

Comment: If this solve your problem, feel free to accept the answer!